# How can I remove Change Owner button from a List View in Salesforce?

Tags: list

How can I remove the Change Owner button from a ListView in Salesforce?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce offers many standard buttons for list views, including many [Mass Quick Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mass_quick_actions_create.htm&type=5). For example, on a "Leads" list view, the "Change Owner" and "Change Status" buttons are available.

To add or remove list view buttons for Standard Objects, follow the steps in [Customize Search Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_searchlayout.htm&type=5).

To add or remove list view buttons for Custom Objects, follow the steps in [Customize Search Layouts for Custom Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizing_search_layouts.htm&type=5).

In Lightning, Go to setup --> Object Manager --> select the object --> Select search layout for Classic --> edit the list view --> deselct the button(**Change owner [MassChangeOwner]**) from there --> save

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess we can't remove the change owner button from Recently viewed list view(tried it on Custom objects).